# Update php hard coded content using another php

Tags: php

This is a single user login verification php file. when the login php submits the hashed password and username this verify.php checks the data posted by login.php and if they are correct it'll redirect to the relevant index.php. This works well, now how to update the password using another php Command?? Using Form Submit command.

```
    <?php 
         if ($_POST['user'] == "ppks82" && 
         md5($_POST['pass']) =="9f5tf71ca91p693a36c403d75a377864") { 
         session_start(); 
         $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user']; 
         header('Location: index.php'); 
         exit();
         }
         else {  
               header('Location: login.php'); 
              }
    ?>
```

Comment: How to update a password? Use a database to store the username and password. Also use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you can't use a database and will only ever have one user, you could save the password in a text file outside of the document root.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But can i update the password then by using form submit method? I want to make possible password change for the user..

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's something to get you started:

This is your verify.php:

```
<?php

if ($_POST['user'] == "ppks82" && 
    md5($_POST['pass']) == file_get_contents("password.txt") { 

    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user']; 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit;
} else {  
    header('Location: login.php'); 
}

?>
```

Now make another file called changepw.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (empty($_POST['user'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    file_put_contents('password.txt', md5($_POST['password']));
    echo 'password changed.';
    exit;
}

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    New password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now make another file called password.txt and put `9f5tf71ca91p693a36c403d75a377864`.

If possible, move password.txt outside of the document root, and access it with `../password.txt` within php.

Comment: Really dude.. Thank you very much.. really appreciate you help.. i'll try this out definitely.